making disks conditional in a vmware .ovf file via the powershell sdk for vsphere
So, one of our deliverables is a vmware .ova file. In the past we had two sizes for deployment, "small" and "enterprise". We have 2 sets of hardware resources for this case. We recently moved our build from vmware vstudio to using packer.io, and the individual responsible for the work made use of the powershell api to automate some aspects of the vsphere build process.
Sadly he left the company and I don't know the powershell api very well, or the powershell language. I am trying to provide one of two harddisks on the VM depending on whether the admin chooses small or enterprise. Hand-hacking the .ovf has proven that this works, but I have been unable to get the powershell api to produce the same.
It works like so
$deleteNames = "Item"
$ovfConfigUri = "http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"

($xmlDoc.Envelope.VirtualSystem.VirtualHardwareSection.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $deleteNames -contains $_.Name }) |
ForEach-Object {
    # Remove each node from its parent

    $parentNode = $_.ParentNode
    $origItem = $_
    Write-Host "Element:", $_.ElementName

and now a switch/case on the type of the resource, so we can replace vcpu and memory.
        Switch ( $origItem.ResourceType ) {
        "3" {
            # vCPU
            Write-Host "Customizing vCPU settings"

            $enterpriseClone = $origItem.Clone()
            $smallClone = $origItem.Clone()

            [void]$parentNode.RemoveChild($origItem)

            # Enterprise
            $enterpriseCloneOvfAttr = $xmlDoc.CreateAttribute('ovf', 'configuration', $ovfConfigUri)
            $enterpriseCloneOvfAttr.Value = "enterprise"
            $enterpriseClone.Attributes.Append($enterpriseCloneOvfAttr)
            $enterpriseClone.ElementName = "4 virtual CPU"
            $enterpriseClone.VirtualQuantity = "4"
            $enterpriseClone.Reservation = "6144"
            [void]$parentNode.AppendChild($enterpriseClone)


            # Small
            $smallCloneOvfAttr = $xmlDoc.CreateAttribute('ovf', 'configuration', $ovfConfigUri)
            $smallCloneOvfAttr.Value = "small"
            $smallClone.Attributes.Append($smallCloneOvfAttr)
            $smallClone.ElementName = "2 virtual CPU"
            $smallClone.VirtualQuantity = 2
            $smallClone.Reservation = "2048"
            
            [void]$parentNode.AppendChild($smallClone)
        }

this technique works for vcpu and memory, but not for the drives.
            "17" {
            # Hard drive
            Write-Host "Customizing Disk settings"

            if ( $origItem.ElementName -eq "Hard disk 1" ) {
                Write-Host "Hard disk 1 for small deployment"
                $smallClone = $origItem.Clone()
                [void]$parentNode.RemoveChild($origItem)

                $smallCloneOvfAttr = $xmlDoc.CreateAttribute('ovf', 'configuration', $ovfConfigUri)
                $smallCloneOvfAttr.Value = "small"
                $smallClone.Attributes.Append($smallCloneOvfAttr)

The small and enterprise tags are not added to the Item like with vcpu and memory.
So, does anyone understand why? I am currently at a loss.
Thank you.
